# After fork(), how can I prevent the child process from reading unnecessary data?

Tags: linux, kernel, fork

I am new to OS. I recently learned that during fork() we use `COW (copy-on-write)` to improve efficiency. But if we copy the pagetables of the parent process, then theoretically the child process can read the data of the parent process, even if the child process does not need it. For example, if the space of the parent process is 0x0000 ~ 0x2000, and the space of the child process only needs 0x0000 ~ 0x1000, in this case, the data between 0x1000 ~ 0x2000 can still be read by the child process. This feels very insecure, is there something wrong with my understanding? Or is there any other technique that allows us to avoid this situation?

Comment: Re "This feels very insecure", what's your threat model exactly?

Comment: @Tsyvarev so 0x1000 ~ 0x2000 space is still mapped in child process pagetable. even child process dose not need this mapping relation and child will never access these speac?

Comment: Upon `fork()` call, a child process is granted access to **all data** which a parent process has **at the time of the call**. This is a **specification** of the `fork` function, whenever COW is used or not. It is unrelated whether a child needs these data or not: all of them are accessible.